# Node is still null from XPathExpression evalution even after adding it

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I am legitimately stuck here. I currently have this method:

```
public void set(Class<? extends ParentXMLModule> parent, Class<? extends XMLModule> moduleClass, String moduleValue, ContinuingMap<String, String> attributeMapping) {
    System.out.println("SET par " + parent + " AND mod " + moduleClass);
    try {
        final Map<String, String> rawAttributeMapping = attributeMapping.getRaw();
        final XMLModule module = XMLModule.of(moduleClass);

        System.out.println("NO PRE MOD " + module.getTag() + "?? " + (document.getElementsByTagName(module.getTag()).getLength() == 0));

        ParentXMLModule parentModule = XMLConstants.MAIN_BODY_MODULE;
        if (parent != null) parentModule = (ParentXMLModule) XMLModule.of(parent);
        Validate.isTrue(parentModule.getChildXMLModules() == null || parentModule.getChildXMLModules().contains(module.getClass()), "Parent module must accept child.");

        Element moduleElement = (Element) expressions.getExpression(module.getTag()).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
        if (moduleElement != null) {
            moduleElement.setTextContent(moduleValue);
        } else {
            moduleElement = document.createElement(module.getTag());
            moduleElement.setTextContent(moduleValue);

            final XPathExpression expression = expressions.getExpression("(" + parentModule.getTag() + ")[1]");
            Node parentNode = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            if (parentNode == null) {
                System.out.println((parentNode == null) + "VAL");
                set(null, parentModule.getClass());
                System.out.println("FROM " + parentModule.getTag() + ": " + document.getElementsByTagName(parentModule.getTag()).getLength());
                parentNode = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            }
            System.out.println((parentNode == null) + "VAL2");
            parentNode.appendChild(moduleElement);
        }

        if (module.getXMLAttributes() != null) {
            final Element finalModuleElement = moduleElement;
            module.getXMLAttributes().forEach(xmlAttribute -> {
                final String attributeName = xmlAttribute.getName();

                String value = rawAttributeMapping.containsKey(attributeName) ? rawAttributeMapping.get(attributeName) : xmlAttribute.getDefaultValue();
                if ((xmlAttribute.getValidValues() == null || !xmlAttribute.getValidValues().contains(value)) && xmlAttribute.isRequired())
                    value = xmlAttribute.getDefaultValue();

                finalModuleElement.setAttribute(attributeName, value);
            });
        }

        System.out.println("POST MOD " + module.getTag() + "?? " + (document.getElementsByTagName(module.getTag()).getLength() > 0));
        System.out.println("--------------------------- for " + module.getTag());
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but this post is focused on these lines

```
final XPathExpression expression = expressions.getExpression("(" + parentModule.getTag() + ")[1]");
            Node parentNode = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            if (parentNode == null) {
                System.out.println((parentNode == null) + "VAL");
                set(null, parentModule.getClass());
                System.out.println("FROM " + parentModule.getTag() + ": " + document.getElementsByTagName(parentModule.getTag()).getLength());
                parentNode = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            }
            System.out.println((parentNode == null) + "VAL2");
            parentNode.appendChild(moduleElement);
```

I get the debug output of doing

```
handler.set(ContributorsParentModule.class, ContributorModule.class, "A contributor.", ContinuingMap.from("contribution", "Helping.").add("uuid", "a-u-u-i-d"));
```

(with `handler` being the class with the set method in it) as

```
SET par class com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.xml.module.impl.general.main.parents.ContibutorsParentModule AND mod class com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.xml.module.impl.general.main.ContributorModule
NO PRE MOD contributor?? true
trueVAL
SET par null AND mod class com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.xml.module.impl.general.main.parents.ContributorsParentModule
NO PRE MOD contributors?? true
falseVAL2
POST MOD contributors?? true
--------------------------- for contributors
FROM contributors: 1
trueVAL2
```

Let me break this up for you to have a better understanding.

```
SET par class com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.xml.module.impl.general.main.parents.ContibutorsParentModule AND mod class com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.xml.module.impl.general.main.ContributorModule
NO PRE MOD contributor?? true
trueVAL
```

is where it stops and starts the set method to create the parent module. This is the debug creation of the parent module

```
SET par null AND mod class com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.xml.module.impl.general.main.parents.ContributorsParentModule
NO PRE MOD contributors?? true
falseVAL2
POST MOD contributors?? true
--------------------------- for contributors
```

and this is the code continuing after setting the parent module

```
FROM contributors: 1
trueVAL2
```

I then get the NPE of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.xml.DocumentHandler.set(DocumentHandler.java:119)
at com.github.wesjd.overcastmappacker.OvercastMapPacker.main(OvercastMapPacker.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

which is saying that `parentNode` is null.

Now, does this make sense to you? Getting all of the tags by the name of the parent after the parent module creation is greater than 0, but evaluating my XPathExpression from `expressions.getExpression("(" + parentModule.getTag() + ")[1]")` returns null representing that there is no parent module in the document.

Have I lost my mind or am I just getting a case of being a noob with an API?

Comment: Which line is line # 119?  There is only ONE place in the code you've shown that outputs `System.out.println((parentNode == null) + "VAL2");`.  Therefore the failure where it's false is in a separate invocation of `set()` from the debug output that comes first.  You really should be debugging this in your IDE debugger, single-stepping through the code.

Comment: Have just decided to use DOM, I've been debugging it and have just found that hassling with something I know little to nothing about is just going to waste time.